# Angular 2 deploy to and consume from CDN

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I consume my own Angular 2 assets via CDN with paths relative to the CDN and not to the website displaying them?

I am deploying all of my Angular 2 build assets (`dist/`: scripts, styles, images and fonts) to a CDN, so the website consuming these assets is on an entirely different domain.

*Example:*

- Website is at http://localhost:8080/
- CDN is at http://localhost:4200/ (the /dist folder of the Angular 2 output)

When I load the website, my Angular 2 scripts are properly loaded including the bundled styles. But, all of the paths to images and fonts end up pointing to the website's relative path instead of the CDN's.

Do I need to create custom directives to describe that the assets are hosted somewhere else? This seems like it will be a common problem for many Angular 2 devs...

The only similar question I found was: [Load css from a CDN in an Angular 2 Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39931441/load-css-from-a-cdn-in-an-angular-2-component)

Comment: Yes, relative URLs are always resolved relative to the main HTML page, not the individual assets (except for CSS). How about you simply keep the relative layout unchanged and deploy to `localhost:4200/dist/`?

Comment: Well, as a work-around, I was able to create a directive for `img` that overrides the src URL prefixed by a CDN path if it's set in the document globally (i.e. document['cdn']). However, this isn't really a long-term solution.

Comment: Deploying has to support a separate website and separate CDN and users will always browse the site via the website. As a result, images in Angular templates are being resolved from the website. I know this is how browsers work. But, I believe Angular should have a more robust method for loading assets entirely from a CDN when the scripts themselves are running on a CDN. That's why I'm curious if there are alternatives to something like what I did: custom directives.